# user access on all computers in the Network with his settings loaded via server

Tags: 12.04, networking, user-profile

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed on three computers. I also have a ubuntu server. 
What I want is, User should be able to log in to any of the three systems in the server when the user logs in. His settings and the folders related to his will be mounted automatically.

I mean, getting user settings and the network drives mounted automatically depending on the users login. I had seen this on a Mac systems but I am new to Ubuntu and this group. Sorry if this is a wrong place to ask this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NFS (network file sharing) protocol to mount the home directories of the users to each of the workstations. You will find a guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

The workstations will mount the home directories from the server; the home directories (/home/user etc.) contain all usual configuration files.

NFS has some drawbacks, and there are alternatives However, if you work within a local LAN, preferably behind a NAT / firewall, NFS will give you great performance at the cost of (relatively) little configuration.